# openssl cms - verify with crl does not work

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, x509certificate

I am trying to verify CMS data using openssl c++ library. I generated some test certificates tree. For the purpose of the test i have:

- certificate bundle: x.crt
- revocation list: y.crl
- input message: data.txt

I tested that everything works fine by running following CRL commands:

```
cat x.crt y.crl > bundle.crt
openssl cms -verify -inform smime -CAfile bundle.crt -crl_check_all < data.txt
```

The output seems correct, now it's time for code:

```
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_CMS_strings();
    ERR_load_X509_strings();
    
    X509_STORE* _certificateStore = X509_STORE_new();
    
    BIO* crlBio = BIO_new_file("y.crl", "r");
    X509_CRL* crl = PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL(crlBio, NULL, 0, NULL);
    X509_STORE_set_flags(_certificateStore, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL );
    std::cout << "add crl: " << X509_STORE_add_crl(_certificateStore, crl) << std::endl;
    
    BIO* certificateBio = BIO_new_file("x.crt", "r");
    X509* certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(certificateBio, NULL, 0, NULL);
    std::cout << "add cert: " << X509_STORE_add_cert(_certificateStore, certificate) << std::endl;
    
    BIO* inBio = BIO_new_file("data.txt", "r");
    BIO* _cmsBio{nullptr};
    CMS_ContentInfo* _cms = SMIME_read_CMS(inBio, &_cmsBio);
    
    BIO* _outBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    
    if (!CMS_verify(_cms, NULL, _certificateStore, _cmsBio, _outBio, 0 ))
    {
        unsigned long err;
        while( ( err = ERR_get_error() ) != 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "SSL Error - code: " << err << ", lib: " << ERR_GET_LIB(err) << ", reason: " << ERR_GET_REASON(err) << ", msg: " << ERR_reason_error_string(err) << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

After running the code above i am getting the following output:

> SSL Error - code: 772378724, lib: 46, reason: 100, msg: certificate verify error

After some debugging it seems that when i remove X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK and X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL everything is ok. I tried loading certificate as bundle:

```
    BIO* certificateBio = BIO_new_file("bundle.crt", "r");
    X509* certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(certificateBio, NULL, 0, NULL);
    std::cout << "add cert: " << X509_STORE_add_cert(_certificateStore, certificate) << std::endl;
```

But that also does not seems to be working.
Am i handling CRL in wrong way ?